# codeigniter upload form not working

Tags: forms, codeigniter, file-upload

I've never used code igniter and I'm trying to make a quick admin form that includes an image upload input. My admin form is up and has a route/url that I can reach, but the save function is not working correctly. I'm getting a 404 error when I click my submit button.

I believe the issue is with the line form_open_multipart('dashboard_save/do_upload') in views/admin/Dashboard.php. I don't think the do_upload function is being reached. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

***new detail:** I am able to reach my controller with form_open_multipart('dashboard_save') using an index function... but I'm not able to reach any other function such as form_open_multipart('dashboard_save/upload') using an upload function in controller dashboard_save.

**CONTROLLERS**

### controllers/admin/Dashboard_save.php

```
<?php

   class Dashboard_save extends CI_Controller
   {

      public function __construct()
      {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
      }

      public function index()
      {
        // die('got here 2');
         $this->load->view('admin/dashboard_view', array('error' => ' ' ));
      }

      public function do_upload()
      {
        // die('got here!!');
         $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/';
         $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
         $config['max_size']      = 100;
         $config['max_width']     = 1024;
         $config['max_height']    = 768;
         $this->load->library('upload', $config);

         if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
         {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('dashboard_view', $error);
         }

         else
         {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $this->load->view('dashboard_save', $data);
         }
      }
   }
?>
```

**VIEWS**

### views/admin/Dashboard.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <div id="main-wrapper">
    <div id="main-container">
      <div id="main-body">
        <div id='main-form-body'>
          <p>Configure front end here.</p>
          <div id='admin-form-container'> 
            <?php echo form_open_multipart('dashboard_save/do_upload');?>
            <form id="admin-form" method="" action="">
              <div class='form-field'>
                <div class='label-wrapper'><label for='main_img'>Main Image</label></div>
                <input type = "file" name = "userfile" size = "20" />
              </div>
            <div class='form-field'>
              <button id="submit-search" type="submit" class="button" title="Submit" value = "upload">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### views/admin/Dashboard_save.php

```
<html>
   <head><title>Dashboard Save</title></head>
   <body>
      <h3>testing dashbord submit</h3>
      <ul>
         <?php foreach ($upload_data as $item => $value):?>
         <li><?php echo $item;?>: <?php $value;?></li>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
      <p><?php echo anchor('upload', 'Upload Another File!'); ?></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: open network tab in console.then you can see how you should set path

Answer (score 1):

Hi first to check your do_upload function has been called or not . if yes then to please check you have loaded in upload library or not . if not so please upload library and than to use below code

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <div id="main-wrapper">
    <div id="main-container">
      <div id="main-body">
        <div id='main-form-body'>
          <p>Configure front end here.</p>
          <div id='admin-form-container'>        
            <form id="admin-form" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url()?>/dashboard_save/do_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class='form-field'>
                <div class='label-wrapper'><label for='main_img'>Main Image</label></div>
                <input type = "file" name = "userfile" size = "20" />
              </div>
            <div class='form-field'>
              <button id="submit-search" type="submit" class="button" title="Submit" value = "upload">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, I am attempting to call do_upload through the multipartform call form_open_multipart('dashboard_save/do_upload'); -- dashboard_save is the controller and do_upload is the function inside the controller.


I attempted to load the upload library with this line $this->load->library('upload', $config); is there an actually library not included in core that I need to install to have this line work?

Comment: when you facing 404 error after uploading any image ot before to call do_upload function ???????

Answer (score 1):

You have used two times the `form` tag. This is why its taking last one and showing error. Remove one FORM tag. Here is your view file code revised

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <div id="main-wrapper">
    <div id="main-container">
      <div id="main-body">
        <div id='main-form-body'>
          <p>Configure front end here.</p>
          <div id='admin-form-container'> 
            <?php $attributes = array('id' => 'admin-form'); echo form_open_multipart('dashboard_save/do_upload', $attributes);?>
              <div class='form-field'>
                <div class='label-wrapper'><label for='main_img'>Main Image</label></div>
                <input type = "file" name = "userfile" size = "20" />
              </div>
            <div class='form-field'>
              <button id="submit-search" type="submit" class="button" title="Submit" value = "upload">Submit</button>
            </div>
          <?php echo form_close();?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

No test it. I have removed `form` open & close tag which you wrote manually, at same time use only `form_open_multipart()` & `form_close()` for accomplish same task

Comment: Thanks for this revision! However I'm still seeing a 404.

Comment: sorry I was missed the `echo` in before `form_close()` function. You may test now. code revised again

Comment: Hello, thanks again! I'm still seeing a 404 unfortunately. The url is my baseurl/admin to get to my form. The save function is not url accessible.

Comment: show your URL you see in browser. and make sure you set correct URL for `base_url` in config.php. also write the code you put in `.htaccess`

Comment: I think my url is okay, I am able to get my admin router working which was neat. So www.myurl/admin works perfectly to get to my form. The issue seems to be "how do I properly invoke do_upload() in my controller?" -- Like I said this is my first glance at codeiginter so I could easily be missing a very basic item o_o

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124367/discussion-between-rejoanul-alam-and-thisbetterwork).

Comment: have you tried by changing your method name? because `do_upload` is system's method name. You may use `public function uploader()` instead `public function do_upload()`

Comment: I would like to make use of the systems do_upload(). It's just not working for me.